# Getting the CANNOT_PURCHASE for actions.type.DigitalPurchaseCheckResult for supported locale (en-US) and enabled Access Play purchases app

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

Getting the CANNOT_PURCHASE for actions.type.DigitalPurchaseCheckResult for supported locale (en-US) and enabled Access Play purchases app

Scenario:

1. Actions Console > Directory information > Additional Information > Do your Actions use the Digital Purchase API to perform transactions of digital goods? - YES:
2. Actions Console > Brand verification:

- Websites: connected website (https://my_website.com/)
- Android apps: My App, com.mycompany.app, Status - Connected, Access Play purchases - enabled

3. Actions Console > Scenes > DigitalPurchaseCheck completed according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/digital/dev-guide-digital-subscriptions#2a)
4. Main Invocation uses the DigitalPurchaseCheck scene as a Transition.
5. Calling test app and the webhook handling the "if scene.slots.status == "FINAL" && session.params.DigitalPurchaseCheck.resultType == "CAN_PURCHASE"" condition is never called. Instead, the webhook handling the "else if scene.slots.status == "FINAL"" is called.
6. The webhookRequest received during the DigitalPurchaseCheck validation looks like following:

```
{
  "requestJson": {
    "handler": {
      "name": "cannotPurchaseHandler"
    },
    "intent": {
      "name": "",
      "params": {
        "DigitalPurchaseCheck": {
          "original": "",
          "resolved": {
            "resultType": "CANNOT_PURCHASE",
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.transactions.v3.DigitalPurchaseCheckResult"
          }
        }
      },
      "query": ""
    },
    "scene": {
      "name": "DigitalPurchaseCheck",
      "slotFillingStatus": "FINAL",
      "slots": {
        "DigitalPurchaseCheck": {
          "mode": "REQUIRED",
          "status": "SLOT_UNSPECIFIED",
          "value": {
            "resultType": "CANNOT_PURCHASE",
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.transactions.v3.DigitalPurchaseCheckResult"
          },
          "updated": true
        }
      }
    },
    "session": {
      "id": "ABwppHHCRgAM0p9S2851n8Z02SreJqDQPeP1dS5qeX6ywHjLEKz0ZTOZqch4uNNaOhTORcqlWXgGSa31Nq3zxJ0mAYE",
      "params": {
        "DigitalPurchaseCheck": {
          "resultType": "CANNOT_PURCHASE",
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.transactions.v3.DigitalPurchaseCheckResult"
        }
      },
      "typeOverrides": [],
      "languageCode": ""
    },
    "user": {
      "locale": "en-US",
      "params": {
        "tokenPayload": {...}
```

As you can see that the locale supports Digital Transactions: `"locale": "en-US"` but the result is always: `"resultType": "CANNOT_PURCHASE"`

The documentation contains interesting comment: "2. a. Validate transaction requirements: It’s a good practice to make sure the user’s account is set up to perform transactions before giving them the option to make a purchase. This step includes **checking that the user has a payment method configured** and **they’re in a locale where digital transactions are supported**. To do so, you should transition to a scene that performs a digital purchase check."

So, in my case, the second condition has met: **they’re in a locale where digital transactions are supported**.

But it looks like the first condition (**checking that the user has a payment method configured**) may cause the validation failing. I'm using my dev account for testing. But the documentation doesn't mention anything else that should be configured to test transaction flow.

Tested in emulator and real devices (Home Mini, Nest Hub, Google Assistant on Android).

Could you please help!

Comment: @NickFelker could you please help! Thanks.

Comment: So the issue is that the DigitalPurchaseCheck fails for your account, though the locale is generally correct?

Comment: @NickFelker Yes, correct.

Comment: Hi @NickFelker any updates?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a payment method configured for your account? When I run the transaction sample my account passes the check.

Comment: @NickFelker The GPC account associated with the same email address as the Assistant Console and Firebase projects. The GPC account's payment settings are configured: the validated Bank account, taxes,... Not sure what else should be done.

Comment: When I'm signing in to the GPC I see the prompt to chose an account I want to use. There is only a single account to choose from. And as I mentioned, this account has the same email address as the Assistant project.

Comment: The Google Cloud Platform -> My Billing Account and Payment Settings also configured. The only difference is in the Payment Settings -> Payment Users -> User points to the company email which is different from my dev account email. Not sure if it is make any difference.

Comment: The payment method in question should be GPay / Settings -> Payments in Assistant

Comment: @NickFelker you mentioned a GPay. I presume it's the Google Pay. The docs doesn't even mentioned about that. Anyway, I "googled" it and found this link (Set up payments for Google Assistant on speaker or display): https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7276665?hl=en
Followed all steps. When I tried "4. Tap Assistant settings  Payments and then Next." I got the message: "Payments aren't currently available on Google Assistant".
Tried my different accounts as well for the sanity check. The same error message.
Not sure how you did it.

Comment: As outlined in the documentation here https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-gpay the Google Pay is used for the for physical goods transactions. It isn't a requirement for the non-consumable digital transactions.
It seems that at this point developers left without an ability to test non-consumable digital transactions. It is very critical, because without it we cannot release subscriptions support. That in turn makes a development on Assistant platform unsustainable.

Comment: Okay, well it seems like the error you are getting in Assistant: "Payments aren't currently available on Google Assistant" is likely the same reason why you're failing the DigitalPurchaseCheck. Is there any more to the error to more precisely diagnose it?

Comment: @NickFelker I managed to setup the Google Pay on my phone with the CC.
But when I go to the Google Home > Assistant Settings > Payments, I'm still getting the error: "Payments aren't currently available on Google Assistant".

So, the Google Pay setup with a few Payment methods. The only catch is that my bank doesn't support "contactless" way of payment via Google Pay.

No sure, what else could be done.

Comment: Is there any payment you can setup on that account, like a credit card?

Comment: @NickFelker Yes, I have a CC associated with that account in Google Pay as a Payment Method. It has  been used to pay the Google Play Apps Developer Registration Fee. So, we can say that it has been setup. But still, when I go to the Google Home > Assistant Settings > Payments and Security I see the error: `Payments aren't currently available on the Google Assistant`
Similar question posted 1 year ago: https://support.google.com/googlenest/thread/9842863?hl=en
Still no answer.

Comment: Is your country/language in a place that supports digital payments on Assistant?

Comment: The official Assistant developer documentation only mentions `countries` where the action with digital transactions support could be deployed to. 
Very few said about the testing: "When testing your project, you can enable the sandbox mode in the Actions console to test your Action without charging a payment method. To enable the sandbox mode, follow these steps: In the Actions console, click Test in the navigation > Settings > Enable the Development Sandbox option."
It's been done. But nothing is working :-(

Comment: @NickFelker Any suggestions?

Comment: @NickFelker Have you given up on this issue?

Comment: I have passed along this question to other members of the team and they're investigating what is happening in your case.

Comment: @NickFelker Thanks for that. I really appreciate it! I have some idea. How about me adding you as an Alpha tester? Could you please send your test Google account to the `support@voiceactivity.com`. Then I will email back to you an opt-in link. You would be able at least to test the action for your configured account. Another option is - send to me the Alpha tester's opt-in link to try to run your POC project that works for you. But I need to figure out how to send to you my dev account email.

Comment: But ideally, it would be great if you could share a Gist of your source code handling the purchase flow validation and entitlements checks (webhooks). Also would be helpful  to see the /scenes/DigitalPurchaseCheck.yaml or whatever you called it. Again, the docs says:
`1. Set up a digital purchases API client...
2. Gather information:
2. a. Validate transaction requirements -> that is where we're failing.
2. b. Gather available inventory...`
Does order matter? In my case #2 goes first (handled by scene) then #1 followed by #2b,...(handled by webhooks, e.g creating and using jwtClient)

Comment: Update: still cannot get ride of this error - CANNOT_PURCHASE. Not sure what is the reason. Developers from Google saying that it works for them,. I live in New Zealand but I have an active Google Pay account (the same as I'm using for the action) but doesn't help. So, it could be a location issue?? Anyway, I ended up with implementing a feature toggle to turn support of DT on | off. So, until Google fix it, try this way: 1. Create a flow as if the DT were supported but with the toggle OFF (DT disbaled), 2. Test the action and submit it for review, 3.Don't forget to turn your DT toggle ON.